# which-func should not show eglot information in modeline

Tags: mode-line, eglot, which-function-mode

Trying to get the modeline to show the current c++ function point is in, I modified my modeline in the following way:

```el
    (setq-default mode-line-format
              (quote
               (#(" " 0 1
              ())
            mode-line-modified
            "    "
            mode-line-buffer-identification
            "    "
            (line-number-mode "%l/")
            (:eval (number-to-string (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))        
            "    "
            mode-line-misc-info
            "    "
            )))
```

All is fine, except that now also `[eglot:project]` is shown in the modeline which I don't want. How can I remove that but keep the function name information (included in mode-line-misc-info)?

The value of `mode-line-misc-info` as reported by `C-h v` is:

```el
((eglot--managed-mode (" [" eglot--mode-line-format "] ")) (which-function-mode (which-func-mode (#1="" which-func-format " "))) (global-mode-string (#1# global-mode-string)))
```

Comment: What is the value of `mode-line-misc-info`? Do `C-h v mode-line-misc-info` to get it and add it to your question.

Comment: mode-line-misc-info is a variable defined in ‘bindings.el’.

Its value is
((eglot--managed-mode
  (" [" eglot--mode-line-format "] "))
 (which-function-mode
  (which-func-mode
   (#1="" which-func-format " ")))
 (global-mode-string
  (#1# global-mode-string)))

Comment: So what happens if you get rid of the first element of `mode-line-misc-info` by evaluating the following form: `(setq mode-line-misc-info (cdr mode-line-misc-info))`. Does that look more like what you want? N.B. untested and no warranty is provided: you might want to do that in a throw-away session of Emacs, just in case.